# Is structural (duck) typing compatible with LSP?

Tags: python, types, duck-typing, liskov-substitution-principle, structural-typing

Does structural sub-typing make it impossible to use LSP in some cases? For example, say I have a Python* setup with nominal typing like

```py
class Foo(ABC):
    def frobnicate(self) -> int:
        """ frobnicate in a general fashion """

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def frobnicate(self) -> int:
        """ frobnicate in a particular fashion """

def bar(f: SubFoo) -> int:
    return f.frobnicate()
```

I can be sure in `bar` that I have a `SubFoo` and because of LSP I know that calling it will "frobnicate in a particular fashion". That's all fine. Now suppose I use structural sub-typing instead (note the `Protocol`)

```py
class Foo(Protocol):
    def frobnicate(self) -> int:
        """ frobnicate in a general fashion """

class SubFoo(Foo, Protocol):
    def frobnicate(self) -> int:
        """ frobnicate in a particular fashion """

def bar(f: SubFoo) -> int:
    return f.frobnicate()
```

I can't be sure in `bar` I have a `SubFoo` because a `Foo` also satisfies that protocol, and so I may, heaven forbid, "frobnicate in a general fashion". That is, LSP doesn't apply because there's no difference between subtypes and supertypes.

*I've used Python as an example cos that's what I know. This is a language agnostic question, but I realise it may be due to Python specifics

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are wondering? On the one hand, LSP is about being able to *substitute* child for parent class, or in other words that the child is structurally identical to the parent class. On the other hand, Protocols are only about structure, so the restriction of ``SubFoo.frobnicate`` is entirely equivalent to ``Foo.frobnicate`` – neither frobnicates in a more general fashion.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm wondering if a) LSP can't be assumed in the presence of duck-typing or b) where I've misunderstood something

Comment: Yeah, I'm just typing up an answer going in that direction. ;)

Answer (score 2):

LSP is a statement of consistency, not implementation.

> Subtype Requirement: Let ϕ(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then ϕ(y) should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

Note how LSP is merely about types and subtypes in general – not *nominal*, *structural* or other subtypes in specific.

Paraphrased, one can say that "whatever a type guarantees, its subtype must guarantee as well". Since structural types are *only* about structure – expressed as type guarantees – this is trivially satisfied.

---

A structural type defines subtyping *only* in terms of structure. For example, `Foo` defines the structural type:

```
{frobnicate: (Self) -> int}
```

Notably, this says that `frobnicate` exists, takes a `Foo` and returns an `int`. It *does not* say anything about how that happens, or what relation there is between input and output.
*Importantly, `Foo` does not say whether to `frobnicate` in a general or specific fashion.* The implementation, docstring, or similar is not part of the type.

Likewise, `SubFoo` defines the *exact same* structural type:

```
{frobnicate: (Self) -> int}
```

As far as LSP is concerned, both substitutions `SubFoo <: Foo` and `Foo <: SubFoo` are valid: `Foo` and `SubFoo` differ only in ways *not* captured by structural typing, and thus not guaranteed by either type.